# IF NOT EXISTS issue in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

I have to create a stored procedure to add info into the Comments table, then add the commenters name into the Commenters name if it does not exist.  I've been tweaking the code for quiet awhile now, and keep getting a syntax error at line 11.

Not sure I understand how to use IF NOT EXISTS syntax.

```
 DELIMITER //                                                                                                       
 CREATE PROCEDURE AddComment(Name VARCHAR(60), Title VARCHAR(60), Comments VARCHAR(60))                             

 BEGIN                                                                                                              

 INSERT INTO Comments(Name, Title, Comments)                                                                        
 VALUES (Name, Title, Comments);                                                                                    

 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Name                                                                                          
 FROM Commenters                                                                                                    
 WHERE Name = Name)                                                                                                 
 UPDATE Commenters                                                                                                  
 SET Name = Name;                                                                                                   
 END IF;                                                                                                            
 END;                                                                                                               
 //
```

Comment: You need a `THEN` after the condition.

Comment: Thank you. Think the lack of sleep is starting to get to me..